# parse_dates cannot convert string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I try to read a CSV from the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LinkedInLearning/data_cleaning_python_2883183/main/Ch04/challenge/traffic.csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LinkedInLearning/data_cleaning_python_2883183/main/Ch04/challenge/traffic.csv', parse_dates=['time'])
```

But, the time column is still in string format.

```
df.dtypes 
[output]
ip        object
time      object
path      object
status     int64
size       int64
dtype: object
```

Interestingly, when I read a similar csv from a different url, it works. So

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LinkedInLearning/data_cleaning_python_2883183/main/Ch04/solution/traffic.csv', parse_dates=['time'])
```

indeed converts the time column to a datetime object. Why does parse_dates fail in the first link and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's a data cleaning exercise - so investigate the data after this initial pass - what's in the column now - which types are the values, what are the failing cases? Go forth and learn about data cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

There is typo in datetimes:

> 1017-06-19 14:46:24

Possible solution is convert values to `NaT`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], errors='coerce')
```